# How to define place holder in child component and import the other child component in parent component

Tags: angular, components, ngrx

I have a question about angular child component and parent component.

My idear is:

```
Parent component: 

<parent-component>

   <child-component1 ngFor= let car of cars>
     <child-component2></child-component2>
   </child-component1>
</parent-component>
```

so looks like parent component, and in child component 1, can I define a place holder for child component 2?

such as:

```
child component 1

<child-component1 ngFor= let car of cars>
hier ist place holder

</child-component1>
```

as you see, in child component using ngfor I want to give car into child component 2.
any solutions?

thands a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-content`: https://angular.io/guide/content-projection

```
Parent component: 

<parent-component>

   <child-component1>
     <child-component2></child-component2>
   </child-component1>
</parent-component>
```

```
child component 1

<div>Some stuff here</div>
<ng-content></ng-content> // <= this renders child-component2
<div>Other stuff here</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the other question, Can I give ng-content input value? because in child component using ngfor. I have reedit my question

Comment: Hi I have edit my question, I mean, that can I use <ng-content [inputValue]=""></ng-content> ???